# access denied error on `getPresignedPost` method on AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my REST API, I call a `createPresignedPost` method which gives back me as usual an `url` and other `fields`. As the returned url wasn't working, I modified it by `http://${url.split('/')[3]}.s3.amazonaws.com` this. After appending my file, I made `post` request with the url and everything worked fine. But, I opened it now after a month and now it isn't working.
I searched a lot to resolve this issue, created a new `ACCESS KEY ID` and `ACCESS KEY SECRET`, modified policies, tried with new buckets. Also, I am not able to get any simplified method of debugging my errors in amazon s3. Can anyone elaborate what exactly is the problem here. This `Acccess denied` message is too vague to understand.

The XML errror message is:

```xml
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>SYBG5Q84R219PN35</RequestId>
<HostId>CVNuh2YSb6gYqYRWPjlONc7hi8wLKfhCQC09nsmwWJz9oqUJ3mF1Ji5U39PO4Tm0xqrGxb7ql1w=</HostId>
</Error>
```

frontend code

```js
const res = await Axios.get(`RESTAPI`);
const { url, fields } = res.data;
const newUrl = `http://${url.split('/')[3]}.s3.amazonaws.com`;
const formData = new FormData();
const formArray = Object.entries({ ...fields, file: blob });
formArray.forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value as any));
// Uploading file to AWS
await Axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: newUrl,
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',},
        data: formData,
        responseType: 'text',
});
```

backend code

```js
aws.config.update({
accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_VERCEL,
secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY_VERCEL,
region: process.env.AWS_REGION_VERCEL,
signatureVersion: 'v4',
});
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const fileName = `fileName`;
const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 10000000, // seconds
    Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', 0, 1048576], // up to 1 MB
    ],
};
await s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
    if (data) {
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    }
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Upload Failed!', type: 'subtitle' });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the IAM user that the backend uses have permission to perform the `s3:PutObject` action?

Comment: @jellycsc you trying to say about policies? Just an update, tried with CORS and everything worked fine but when I deploy it, the same issue comes up in production now.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about the IAM policies attached to the IAM user.

Comment: no, I was not able to get the proper info about them. The changes that I made were made bucket publicly accessible, added CORS policy. After which I was able to upload file in the desired bucket in dev mode but I am still facing the same issue in prod mode.